# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myArray' was corrupted.- Cant seem to figure out how to remove this error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Code runs however constant error- Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myArray' was corrupted. Cant seem to find any workable solutions. All help is much appreciated.

```
`# include <iostream>
 # include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    int swapHolder = -1;

    int myArray[] = {44, 9, 237, 1, 5, 44, 534, 17, 21, 819};

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)

 {
    if (myArray[index] > myArray[index + 1])
    {
        swapHolder = myArray[index + 1];
        myArray[index + 1] = myArray[index];
        myArray[index] = swapHolder;

      }
}


for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
{
    cout << myArray[index] << ", ";

    cout << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: `myArray[index + 1]` is out of bounds access when `index` is `9` (in the last run of loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in last run of your first for loop , when value of index is 9 `myArray[index + 1]` became `myArray[10]` but the maximum value of index of this array is 9. So in this case you are accessing a memory block which is not assigned to your program by the compiler. That's why you are getting Run-Time error.
Please Replace your first for loop with this one

```
for(int index=0; index<9; index++)
```